# Itext sharp url opens in new windowf

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, itext

I want to open my external urls on ITEXT Sharp pdf to opens in new window.

vdfgdfgfdgdfg
bdf

Can anyone have solution for this ?

```
        new Chunk("Click to open test.txt in Notepad.")
            .SetAction(
              new PdfAction(
                "c:/windows/notepad.exe",
                "test.txt", "open",
                Path.Combine(Utility.ResourceText, "")
              )
          ));
```